# Return a single result from a sub query that matches criteris

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database that stores details of football players, fixtures and which fixture a player was involved in.

I need to create a query that returns a list of all players along with details of the last fixture the player was involved in, but I can't figure out to do this.

The database tables look like this (I've removed unnecessary fields);

```
players (stores details of players)
-------
id : int
name : text
team_id : int

fixtures (stores details of fixture)
-------
id : int
period : text
date : datetime

fixture_players (records which players were involved in which fixtures)
---------------
id : int
player_id : int
fixture_id : int
```

A most recent fixture is the first result from this query

```
"SELECT * FROM fixtures WHERE period = 'FullTime' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1"
```

How do I create a query that merges these three tables together, returns the player and fixture details, but only one fixture per player, and that fixture is the last fixture that the player was involved in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a sub query to give you the last fixtures played by the players. Like this:

```
SELECT p.name, f.period, f.date
FROM fixture_players fp 
JOIN fixtures f on fp.fixture_id = f.id
JOIN ( --Subquery: Last fixture dates played by players
    SELECT fp2.player_id, max(f2.date) lastFixDate 
    FROM fixture_players fp2 join fixtures f2 on fp2.fixture_id = f2.id 
    GROUP BY fp2.player_id --By grouoping player id we can have only one date per player
) a ON a.player_id = fp.player_id and a.lastFixDate = f.date
JOIN players p ON fp.player_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Comment: Thanks, running the query returns "Unknown column 'f.date' in field list" though

Comment: Yes my bad, it should be `max(f2.date) lastFixDate` not `max(f.date) lastFixDate`